# How was the cake poisoned at the Purple Wedding?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I still haven't understood, how was the poison mixed with Joffrey's cake in *game of Thrones* S04E02? Is it explained in the show yet? I have a feeling, I have missed the explanation. As much as I have understood Little finger put the poison in Sansa's necklace which somehow mixed with the cake. But when and how? Please help me understand it.

Comment: the wine was poisoned not cake

Comment: The fact that it was poisoned _wine_ is a significant plot point, since Tyrion poured the wine and thus gets blamed for the death.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the show, it is not explicitly explained how Joffrey was poisoned. The medium of poison is unclear, whether it was the wine or the cake.

However, in S04E06, Grand Maester Pycell presents Sansa's necklace as a proof in the trial against Tyrion. And since Sansa was wearing the necklace throughout the wedding and nobody but Olenna Tyrell goes up near her for a small talk, there would have been no time to mix the poison in the pigeon pie (which you confused as cake). Hence, the poison was certainly mixed in the wine.

Littlefinger & Olenna were directly involved. Olenna even confessed to it in front of Margery in S04E04. Ser Dontos was hired to transfer the poison onto the unsuspecting Sansa.

If you go back to S04E03, you can clearly see the point at which, Olenna takes the poison from Sansa's necklace & puts it in Joffrey's wine.

If you don't want to rewatch the episode, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkhOL.jpg) is a detailed explanation with screenshots from that episode thanks to [r/zephytr](https://www.reddit.com/user/zephyrtr)

Comment: That is an *excellent* set of pics! I watched that episode like a hawk, knowing what was to come, and I missed most of what's described in those pics.

Comment: This theory is wrong because Margery places the cup back at Joffrey's and her table. There are two Kingsguards standing right behind the Royal table at the cutting of the pie, they would have seen the poisoning of the wine. The poison must have come from the pie ... There`s another reason, she could not have poisoned the wine, there was a chance Joffrey would give wine to Margery to chink, Olenna wouldn't have risked that. Keeping Margery safe from eating the pie would have been easier, because Olenna knew Joffrey would be brought the first piece.

Comment: @SystemDown The theory claimed in those pics is incorrect. [Here is the point where Olenna drops the poison in the wine.](http://i.imgur.com/Ajt3ISc.gif) If you go back and listen to the audio during that shot, an audible clink is heard when Olenna lifts her right elbow backward.

Comment: The idea that Joffrey would share his wine with _anyone_ is blatantly out of character, but it's also possible Olenna had already dosed Margaery with an antidote.

Comment: The wine also works better, because of it's [thematic] association to Tyrion, which is whom the murder gets (mostly) pinned on.

Answer (score 1):

The cake was nothing more than dry and full of pigeon guts, after what Joffrey did to it :)

Joffrey was poisoned by The Strangler, a poison that is formed into a crystal through a deeply intricate process- *A Clash of Kings* gives a fairly detailed history and description of how The Strangler is created. Remember at the beginning of Season 2, when Maester Cressen attempted to poison Melisandre by slipping poison into her wine? He, too, attempted to poison her with The Strangler. The Strangler is not "activated", so to speak, until its crystal was placed in a liquid and dissolved. Maester Cressen needed to slip his Strangler crystal into Melisandre's wine, and Olenna needed to somehow get her Strangler crystal into Joffrey's cup.

Olenna's Strangler crystal came from Sansa's necklace (in the books, I believe it was a hairnet) that Dontos gave her. Although it is well hidden on the show, and not something you'd likely pick up on your first watch (assuming you didn't know what was coming), Olenna plucks one of the crystals from Sansa's necklace at one point during the feast. Olenna must have slipped the crystal into Joffrey's cup between then and when the cake was brought out.